# Ionic tabbed slide box icons are not aligned

Tags: ionic-framework

The icons that displayed here:
http://ionic-sarav.rhcloud.com/ionic/tabbedSlideBox/default.html#/ are working fine, though if I copy paste the ***entire*** code and copy-paste it in my `index.html` in my local Ionic project that I created - the icons are not aligned.

[**Screenshot**]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj8TC.png)

Thing is, beside `index.html` - I really didn't change anything, so I'm not really sure what's causing it:

1. The `<a>` tags are with `text-align: center` after rendering ( "computed" in Firebug )
2. I though the Ionic version maybe outdated/too new, but version 1.1.1 works fine vs 1.0.0 in the demo URL.

Another thing to notice is that the code in the demo:

```
<style>
    .slider-slide h3{
        color:#fff;
        margin-top:10px;
    };
    .scroll{ height:100%;};
</style>
```

should make the title "Games content" white ... but it's not affecting it.

## Clarifying my debugging

Checkout my plunker for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3wLO3MNgeMOESSBRA0Vp?p=preview
( code is exactly as in the GitHub example in the link above just I played with the Ionic version to see if maybe I have an outdated version of Ionic )

In my server I did:

```
> I created a new Ionic project, bower.json:
  "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.1"
> I edited files under www
> In www/index.html - I copy pasted the content of index.html from the Plunker
> Plunker works OK, but in my server I have Icons aligned to the left vs centered
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: did you checked in developer options? what is the error?

Comment: there's no error, just the look of the page is different ..., developers options - I'm not sure what can I check, because if I'm taking the code to Plunker for example - it works( because the Ionic libs are not the files from my server, though the version is the same ) ... :/

Comment: ANSWER: my mistake, it doesn't work when I test it in Firefox, but it works ok in Chrome ... :( my bad